# regex replace spaces in text with &nbsp;

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've a html code. like this:

```
<div>
    (<- it is a tab) blaaaa ttoooo
    <span id="span" class="class">Hiii Bye</span>
    (<- these are 4 space character)
    <span id="span" class="class">Welcome   Back</span>
</div>
```

I want to replace any space(s) (only space: `" "`, and not any tab (`\t`)) between `>` and `<` (means the space(s) isn't in a html tag) with `&nbsp;`. (with PHP and RegEX)

So after replacing, my code it it:

```
<div>
    blaaaa&nbsp;ttoooo
    <span id="span" class="class">Hiii&nbsp;Bye</span>
    <-&nbsp;these&nbsp;are&nbsp;4&nbsp;space&nbsp;character
    <span id="span" class="class">Welcome&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Back</span>
</div>
```

How can I do this??

Thank you very much. ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Hooray, yet another programmer who wants to use regex to work with HTML.

Comment: @Matt: and why not just let them?

Comment: Seriously, why do you actually want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but it will work:

```
$output = preg_replace_callback("#>[^<]+<#","replace_spaces",$input);

function replace_spaces($match)
{
     return str_replace(" ","&nbsp;",$match[0]);
}
```

but not for spaces outside of the outermost tags.

Comment: What if there is a > inside an attribute or in a comment? This won't work 100% reliably...and I suspect that is true for any Regex-based solution.  But maybe it's good enough.

Comment: Certainly not 100%. Think of all the javascript that will be mutilated by this regexp.. I think having `<` in an attribute is not valid html btw.

Answer (score 0):

Don't. Use a `whitespace: pre` CSS declaration instead.

Comment: @kikio: No, I mean did you write the HTML many days ago, or some PHP that you haven't given us?